# Convergence of $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \left(\frac 1 n-\ln(1+\frac 1 n)\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Does the series: $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1} \left(\frac 1 n-\ln(1+\frac 1 n)\right)$ converge?

We know that $\ln (1+x) <x$ for $x>0$ so this series behaves like $\frac 1 n - \frac 1 n$ which is $0$, but that's just intuition.

I think the only test that would work is the limit comparison test, but I can't find an expression that would work. Any hints?

**Note:** no integral test nor integrals, nor Taylor, nor Zeta.

Comment: Hint: $\ln (1+x) > x - \frac{x^{2}}{2}$ for $x >0.$ You can prove this without Taylor.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson is that a known identity?

Comment: Simeon has given one proof. There are several others. It is the beginning of how you prove Taylor's Theorem.

Comment: How do you define $\ln$ without calculus?

Comment: It converges.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty+%28+1%2Fn-%5Cln%281%2B+1%2Fn%29

It is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2\left(\frac{1}{n} - \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x - \log(1 + x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\frac{x}{1 + x}}{2x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{2(1 + x)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, by limit comparison $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n} - \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$ converges.

Comment: That substitution saves lives...

Comment: This used L'Hospital's Rule.  I thought the proof was to shown without differential or integral calculus.

Comment: @Dr.MV that's not what OP says.

Comment: Kobe, what is "OP?"

Comment: @Dr.MV the original proposer, GinKin.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$
x - \ln(1+x) = \int_0^x \frac{t}{1+t}dt
$$ 
hence for all $x \geq 0$,
$$
0 \leq x - \ln(1+x) \leq \int_0^x t dt = \frac{x^2}{2}.
$$
Now, you can use the comparision test.

**Edit:** if you don't want integrals, then you can prove the same inequality by studying the variations of the functions
$$
f(x) = x - \ln(1+x),\qquad g(x) = x - \ln(1+x) - \frac{x^2}{2}.
$$

Comment: No integral test...

Comment: It's not the integral test!

Comment: Well, I should've noted no integrals at all..

Comment: @GinKin The integrals are just to help imagine. You can prove the inequality using first derivative test I think

Comment: In other words, we need to prove that $\frac {x^2}2>x-\ln(1+x)$ and then it will follow by comparing to $\frac 1 {n^2}$ that it converges.

Answer (score 1):

By MVT, for any positive $x > 0$, there exists a $\xi \in (0,1)$ such that

$$0 \le x - \log(1+x) = \left(1 - \frac{1}{1+\xi x}\right) x = \frac{\xi x^2}{1 + \xi x} \le x^2$$

This implies the series at hand consists of non-negative terms and its sum is bounded from above by
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n - \log\left(1 + \frac1n\right)\right) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
As a result, the series converges.